# In AngularJS, how can I trigger a loading animation before the ng-view changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-view

I'm working on an app that has "doors" that close and open between transitions. I'm using ng-view to switch between screen and then to eventually populate the screens with data from a local database.

```
<div style="background-image:url('img/trans-left.png');" class="loading door-left"></div>
<div style="background-image:url('img/trans-right.png');" class="loading door-right"></div>

<div id="content" class="scroller" ng-view></div>

var nanoApp = angular.module('nanoApp',['ngRoute']);
nanoApp
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller:'HomeController as homeSlides',
        templateUrl: 'content/home.html'
    })
    .when('/products',{
        controller:'ProductsController as products',
        templateUrl: 'content/products.html'
    });
})
.controller('HomeController', ["$scope",function($scope){

}])
.controller('ProductsController', ["$scope",function($scope){

}]);
```

I need the doors `door-left` and `door-right` to animate closed before the view changes then open when the view loads. The doors are outside the ng-view so I can't use that has the trigger. I could use a trigger when the link/button is clicked but the view will change as the doors close.

I have a jquery function to control the opening and closing but I could use CSS3 if needed/required when using ng-view.

Comment: Maybe you could use `$routeChangeStart/Success` events or put something in the resolve of the routes that controls the animation?